# filter a porperty(List<Foo>) that belong to to object

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Now i want to return a sequence that list of X that its prop1.where(p=>p.a==1).
**i can write this with `Select` clause but my object has many properties.**

something like this(but in true syntax):

```
ctx.MyObject.Where(p=>p.state==1 && prop1.where(p=>p.a==1));
```

**EDIT:** `obj1` with this props(`int` a, `List<Foo>` prop1) and `Foo` has (`int` b,`int` c).

Comment: Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints for hints about making your questions clearer.

Comment: I think you need to be more clear in your question, it's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: Your code looks like valid syntax to me. What do you mean by "true syntax"?

Comment: @CodeInChaos: props1 is List<Foo> and you can't.

Comment: My bad, of course `Where` does return an enumerable and not a bool which makes this code invalid. I still don't understand what you're trying to to/where your problem is.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: second part of "Mark Byers"'s answer. but i don't want set all properties because my object has many properties.

Comment: @maysam_pro: if you don't set them, who will?

Answer (score 3):

Depending what you want to do, try `Any` instead of `Where`:

```
ctx.MyObject.Where(p=>p.state==1 && prop1.Any(p2 => p2.a == 1))
```

Or as you mentioned you can use `Select`:

```
ctx.MyObject
   .Where(p => p.state == 1)
   .Select(p => new
       {
           state = p.state,
           prop1 = p.prop1.Where(p2 => p2.a == 1),
           // other fields...
       }
```

Comment: i know this way but i have so many properties!! and i don't want set them by hand.

Comment: I think, if there is another way to do this needs reflection, and it's not good way, when you can do it like Mark answer.